# Give site directly using client context

Tags: list, site, spcontext, pages

I have many sites in my site collection, and I am wanting to get the pages of one site. Is there anyway to give the site that you want the pages for?
so like clientcontect.get_site('sitename')

Comment: are you working with c# or js?

Comment: I can do it with either

Comment: are you on sp 2010 or 2013?

Comment: I am on sharepoint 2013